# How to tell which group is responsible for your sudo permissions?

Tags: sudo, group, ldap

Say I am part of various groups

```
$ groups
users git engineering ....
```

And I can execute `sudo` in that machine, 
How can I tell which group is responsible for my sudo execution ability ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a group; it could be assigned to your id

Comment: Thanks for the insight. For this case I am certain that sudo ability it is not tied to the user itself but gained with a group association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute:

```
sudo less /etc/sudoers
```

or even just

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers
```

and look for something like the following:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

where the key to your question is the group name following the "%".

See `man sudo.conf` for an excellent explanation of who gets what privileges based on the line "%" line above and other parameters available in `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Comment: Why pass `-f /etc/sudoers`? Isn't that the default?

Comment: Well, I learned something new.  I use it rarely and always just use the `command target` format and am then greeted with the usage message saying to use `-f sudoers` so I do it that way.  I was unaware that it defaulted to the correct file and path with `visudo` alone.  I just tried `visudo` alone and you are right, that is the default.

Comment: Given that the OP might not be the system administrator, why not suggest ``sudo cat /etc/sudoers`` (or maybe ``grep`` or `less`) to reduce the chance that the user will accidentally change the file.

Comment: Thinking about the way it's written @G-Man, I think "_might not_ be" is pretty clearly "_isn't".  That's a great point and I think I should amend the answer; one could certainly cause major problems with an inadvertent keystroke, though they would have to intentionally save it.  Still, read-only solution is a better answer here.

Comment: Thanks @airhuff, with your answer I was able to find the group that enables sudo permissions.

Comment: Great!  Sorry it took me some edits to get it straightened out...